# Why does the .catch() fail to do anything?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot in javascript, and I made a command that sends a message to a specific channel. It worked before, but now it doesn't. I found out, the problem is coming from this part of the code:

```
let sugchannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === "name");

  sugchannel.send(embed).then((msg) =>{
    
    message.delete();

  }).catch((err)=>{
    throw err;
  });
```

I wnet through a lot of similar questions, but nothing solved the problem. Also, it does work, if I change it to

`message.channel.send(embed).then...`

And here's the error message:

```
(node:416) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/cutiefoxy/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runner/cutiefoxy/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)
(node:416) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:416) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:416) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/cutiefoxy/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runner/cutiefoxy/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)
(node:416) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

Comment: to me it looks like that your bot is just missing the permissions to perform that action in your server.

Comment: It has the same permissions as me. I'm the owner. That's exactly why I'm confused.

Comment: Why do you `throw err` inside catch?

Comment: The question as asked is asking about promises and how rejection handlers work. I suspect, though, that you probably want to post a different question asking why `sugchannel.send(embed)` fails with the permissions error you've shown when `message.channel.send(embed)` succeeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the .catch() fail to do anything?

It does do something, it just doesn't do anything useful. There's never any point to `.catch(err => { throw err; })`. All it does is hook up a rejection handler that creates a new promise and rejects it with the same error it received. (There can be a point to having a rejection handler that throws, but not if *all* it does is throw the original error without doing anything else.)

`then` and `catch` create promises. Those promises are fulfilled or rejected depending on what the callbacks do and what they return. If the callback throws, that rejects the promise that was created, which is what your code is doing.

One of the rules of promises is that you must either

1. Handle rejections,

   or
2. Return the promise to something that will handle rejections

Usually you want #2, and then only handle rejections (#1) at the topmost level of your code.

So if this code is the topmost level of your code, remove the `throw err` and instead log or otherwise handle the error. If this isn't at the topmost level of your code, remove the `.catch` entirely and return the promise from `then` so the caller can handle it (or the caller's caller, or the caller's caller's caller, etc.).

This is one reason for using `async` functions when possible, they automatically return the promise chain when you use `await` and `return` within them.